# php download fails at the middle of download

Tags: php, download

I use this script to download files in php.
[Here](http://www.media-division.com/php-download-script-with-resume-option) is the original source where I copied the script.

```
if(file_exists($path)){
        $file_size = filesize($path);
        $file = fopen($path,"rb");
        $chunksize = 2*1024*1024; // how many bytes per chunk
        if($file){
            header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
            header("Pragma: public");
            header("Expires: 0");
            header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$name.$format\"");
            header("Content-Type: $mimetype");

            //check if http_range is sent by browser (or download manager)
            if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])){
                list($size_unit, $range_orig) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
                if ($size_unit == 'bytes'){
                    //multiple ranges could be specified at the same time, but for simplicity only serve the first range
                    //http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-http-range-retrieval-00.txt
                    list($range, $extra_ranges) = explode(',', $range_orig, 2);
                }
                else{
                    $range = '';
                    header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                    exit;
                }
            }
            else{
                $range = '';
            }

            //figure out download piece from range (if set)
            list($seek_start, $seek_end) = explode('-', $range, 2);

            //set start and end based on range (if set), else set defaults
            //also check for invalid ranges.
            $seek_end   = (empty($seek_end)) ? ($file_size - 1) : min(abs(intval($seek_end)),($file_size - 1));
            $seek_start = (empty($seek_start) || $seek_end < abs(intval($seek_start))) ? 0 : max(abs(intval($seek_start)),0);

            //Only send partial content header if downloading a piece of the file (IE workaround)
            if ($seek_start > 0 || $seek_end < ($file_size - 1)){
                header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
                header('Content-Range: bytes '.$seek_start.'-'.$seek_end.'/'.$file_size);
                header('Content-Length: '.($seek_end - $seek_start + 1));
            }
            else
                header("Content-Length: $file_size");

            header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

            set_time_limit(0);
            @fseek($file, $seek_start);

            while(!feof($file)){
                print(@fread($file, $chunksize));
                ob_flush();
                flush();
                if (connection_status()!=0){
                    @fclose($file);
                    exit;
                }
            }
            @fclose($file);
            exit;
        }
        else{
            // file couldn't be opened
            header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
            exit;
        }
    }
    else {
        // file does not exist
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        exit;
    }
```

Now, the problem.
Downloading large files, (e,g > 20MB) sometimes download completes successfully. and Sometimes it breaks at the middle of download. for example I tested and found out that for a 100MB file, after downloading 40MB it failed. (not one time, multiple times.)
In the browser, it seems that the file downloaded completely.  (Firefox and chrome had no Failed text in the download bar. but the "open containing folder" option exists)
some of my friends with very slow internet connection says that the same problem happened to him for smaller files (less than 1 MB). but I never experienced it. (maybe because my internet is not slow)
So the problem is that when someone with slow connection wants to download, at the middle, it breaks for him. (I guess server doesn't send file to him anymore.)
Note1: I have these two headers too:

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
```

And this is an example download file for anyone who wanted to test it:
https://goo.gl/9flVng
Just one more question, isn't it better to send the user to download file with `header: location` directly instead of `readfile(), fread(), ...`?

Sorry for the Long question, Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Might be worth looking into a cdn as another option

Comment: yeah, cdn is a good idea. I haven't experienced it yet, it seems I should test it some time. but about the current problem, my server is a good one. there shouldn't be any problem. Any idea about the script or server config?
I just know that the connection between client and server refuses and doesn't reconnect.
Why does the browser doesn't show "failed" text??

Answer (score 0):

You could try to raise the script's maximum execution time limit, by default its set to 30 seconds. Setting it to 0 removes time limit.

```
set_time_limit (0)
```

Comment: Thank you Luis for the help.
yes, I did it already.
you can see it in the code I provided. but no positive result.
any other help?
I guess the problem is with the server or something related to it, not the script. any idea?